# ¿Por qué thymeleaf en responsivo coge la misma resolucion que en escritorio?

Tags: spring-boot, responsive, thymeleaf

estoy haciendo una web api con spring boot y thymeleaf y en responsivo se ve un poco mal, coge todo el ancho posible;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo porque hace eso en responsivo bajo la resolucion de un movil deberia escalarse a su resolucion, tienen alguna sugerencia ? muchas gracias el codigo esta en https://github.com/Daviddg91/APIUsuariosSpringBoot

Muchas gracias, un saludo !

Edit:

Así es como se ve cuando ajusto el tamaño de la ventana del navegador en modo responsive:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas, si es responsivo normal que te coja todo el ancho,el rectangulo blanco sombreado que lo contiene, se supone ser la pantalla de un movil? , no entiendo como querrías que se viese.

Comment: Lo he editado para que veas mejor cual es el problema, gracias por tu respuesta, un saludo

Comment: No es correcto colocar resuelto en el título de tu pregunta, si encontraste como entonces por favor usa la zona de respuestas justo debajo por favor